# What is this line of code precisely doing?

Tags: javascript

In this five minute video:

"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QWVuubrms18"

precisely from 4:38 the woman shows this code:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class Example extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement){

       navigateToObjectHome(){
          this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                 type: 'standard__objectPage',
                 attributes:{
                       objectApiName : 'Account',
                        actionName: 'home'
                    },
             });
        }

}
```

and she says: " it adds navigation mixing methods to liningElement, to use in our custom class". But the way I see it is other way around if Example class inherit from LightningElement via mixin pattern algo I would like to understand this line:

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({...
```

1 - the "this" is a reference to Example class or navigateToObjectHome method, right?

and secondly:

2 - what "NavigationMixin.Navigate" would be refering to? a property from the NavigationMixin class factory function? this property shpuld point to a function right? because of the receiving parameter

Comment: I think that's taken from the salesforce documentation, more info on that snippet here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation

Answer (score 0):

Answers

1. `this` refers to the scope of the class in which you are in. That means `this` refers to `Example` class itself.
2. `NavigationMixin.Navigate` should be a string constant that is defined inside `'lightning/navigation'`. So if `Navigate` value inside `lightning/navigation` is `"doSomething"`, then `this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]` calls `this.doSomething`, where `doSomething` is the function defined inside your `Example` class

Comment: Good that is the way i understood this, but the woman states: "it adds navigation mixing methods to liningElement, to use in our custom class" and by thta I understand the method comes from liningElement, and it does not make any sense to me.

Comment: it is also very weird to me because if NavigationMixin  is a third part library, so how are we suposed to know which method NavigationMixin.Navigate points to so we can write this in our custom class

Comment: You have to see the value for `NavigationMixin.Navigate` in your app.

Comment: you mean console.log(NavigationMixin.Navigate)

Comment: @Berinjatela Yes correct, log it in console and see whether there is a function with that name in your class.

Comment: the way I was thinking was like this: as Example (custom class) inherit from: "LightningElement" via the mixin patterns so the method would be available in my custom class without me writing it, right? my point being the woman in the video said the mixin pattern adds method to LightningElement and not the way around as I belive is what is happening